# form.is_valid() is returning False when using ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I am creating a form using ModelForm to let the users upload a file along with a description . The is_valid() function isn't returning true and I am really confused. I have searched and **there are many questions with same title as mine but they don't solve my problem.**

here is forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    document = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)

class Meta:
    model = FeedModel
    fields = ['description', 'document']
```

Here is models.py:

```
class FeedModel(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField()
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_created=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        u=self.user
        return reverse('home:feed',u.primary_key)
```

Here is views.py:

```
class PostView(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'home/feedModel_form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user=request.user
            self.object=form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.user=user
            self.object.save()
            logger.error("voila")
            redirect({'home:feed'}, user.id)


        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form })


def feedview(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    return render(request, 'home/feed.html', {'user': user})
```

Here is feedModel_form.html:

```
{% extends 'home/navbar.html' %}
{% block body %}

<div class="form">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include 'home/form.html' %}
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block"  ` 
         name="reg_btn">Post</button>`
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is form.html:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="field-wrap">
    <label>
    {{ field.label_tag }}<span class="req">*</span>
    </label>
    <div>{{ field }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why the form isn't valid, you should check `form.errors`.

One error will be because you have not passed `request.FILES` to the form.

```
form=self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

There may be other errors as well. If you used `{{ form }}` in your template, Django would include the errors automatically. Since you are [rendering the fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), it's up to you to include the errors.

The key problem here is that you have overridden `post`. That means that you're missing out on lots of the code from `CreateView`.

In your case, it looks like you could remove the `post` method, and simply override `form_valid` instead.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object=form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user=user
    self.object.save()
    # Note that you had {'home:feed'} here which was incorrect
    return redirect('home:feed', user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck from quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `document` field expects an uploaded file and is required. In order for the form to actually get the file, you have to also pass it the uploaded file in views.py:

```
form = self.form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```